# Regex: How not to replace specific word in any html tag?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

So let's assume I have a text like this:

```
This is a great test! We're testing something awesome. Click here to <a href="whatever">test it!</a>.
```

I want to add some color to the word "test", but not if it's in an a tag.
I've tried doing this:

```
/(?<!href="(.*?)">)test/
```

But it doesn't work.
It works like this:

```
/(?<!href="whatever">)test/
```

But of course I have many links, so this isn't an option.

The whole code would be something like this:

```
$replacement = preg_replace('/(?<!href="SOLUTION HERE">)test/','<span style="color: #FF0000;">test</span>',$replacement);
```

Expected result:

```
This is a great <span style="color: #FF0000;">test</span>! We're <span style="color: #FF0000;">test</span>ing something awesome. Click here to <a href="whatever">test it!</a>.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick, less reliable way to interact with html strings is with regex.  DomDocument (or similar) is specially designed to parse html and is far more trustworthy.  I'll post the regex way, and if I can manage it, I'll add a DomDocument way.

`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` allows you to match/consume and disqualify substrings then after the pipe you write the pattern for the substring that you actually want to replace.

Pattern: `~(?:<[^>]*>.*?</[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|\btest\b~s`

Replace: `<span style="color: #FF0000;">\0</span>`

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZVANT/1)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b50294f3d80c3e9629d469eaf8ca7d29d0099ea0))

```
$string="This is a great test! We're testing something awesome. Click here to <a href=\"whatever\">test it!</a>.";
$pattern='~(?:<[^>]*>.*?</[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|\btest\b~s';
$replace='<span style="color: #FF0000;">\0</span>';
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$string);
```

Output:

```
This is a great <span style="color: #FF0000;">test</span>! We're testing something awesome. Click here to <a href="whatever">test it!</a>.
```

Comment: Wow! This is great! This also solves many other problems I had (but didn't ask to fix them), it also doesn't change the word "testing", which is really great as well. Thank you, You're awesome! (I never used Dom before (only heard about it), anyway I have 10 words like this, which needs recolor, but I don't see performance issues).

Comment: I aim to please.  Here's how you add more qualifying substrings to your pattern: https://regex101.com/r/6ZVANT/2

Comment: It looks like I still have a little issue, because I want it to work in most html tags. I think I could change it successfully using your code: https://regex101.com/r/6ZVANT/4

Comment: Well, the img tag sucks, because we don't close it. :D