# Regex that matches a string between square brackets except inside a specific html tag

Tags: php, regex, forms, pcre, preg-split

I'm looking for a regex that matches between square braces but ignores input values.

Here is my current code:

```
    $matches = preg_split(
        '#\[([a-zA-Z0-9\._]+)\]#',
        $content,
        null,
        PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
    );
```

Which works but also includes values within `<input value="[string_here]">`

It needs to exclude form input values.

```
Lorem ipsum [this_gets_matched] dolor
<input value="this [doesnt_get] matched"/>this [gets.matched]
<textarea title="this [gets_matched]">this [doesn't.get.matched] lipsum</textarea>
```

Ultimately if it is to be later submitted in a form, it shouldn't get matched.

I realise that parsing html with a regex is a bad idea. This is a temporary work around until the long term fix is implemented.

Thanks

Comment: You say you want to _match_ stuff, but then your example is using `preg_split`. You should add a proper explanation of what you actually need to achieve here first of all.

Comment: (That `<input value="this [doesnt_get] matched">this [gets.matched]</input>` is not actually valid HTML, if(!) that’s what this is supposed to be, is clear I hope …)

Comment: @misorude You have to match something before you can split it out no? I thought the explanation for what I needed to achieve was pretty clear...

preg_match and preg_split use the same pcre rules to first match and in the case of preg_split, then split the results.

Perhaps you could explain the difference in the context of my question so I can better improve it?

Comment: The best way with regex is probably `'~<input(?:\s[^>]*)?>(*SKIP)(*F)|\[([\w.]+)]~'` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2Qyvs/1))

Comment: “Matching” is usually understood as extracting certain parts of the data that match a pattern, possibly including grouping, whereas splitting is … well, just that, splitting the data into parts. But either way, what you actually want to _achieve_ here, is still unclear. Whether we call it matching or splitting, you are probably not doing that for its own sake, but because you want to manipulate your input data in some way. So a proper explanation of what end result you actually want to achieve, should be included - then people might probably be able to suggest _better_ solutions.

Comment: @misorude as I put at the bottom of the original question. This is a temporary work around. I'm specifically not looking for advice on other ways to achieve my end goal. I already have a long term plan for that. In the mean time I need this while the longer term refactoring of the codebase is underway.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Many thanks! Put that in an answer and barring any faults, i'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Or shall we close with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846415/regex-how-not-to-replace-specific-word-in-specific-html-tag?

Comment: But maybe setting up a _proper_ solution would not require that much more time, than your regex wizardry in the first place … Why _insist_ on “I want _my_ temporary workaround, and nothing else” then …? Well, have it your way.

Comment: I wont edit the question to include this, because I still don't believe it is relevant in this case. But i'll add it here for your benefit, and then if you still disagree i'll reconsider.
Multi-lingual support added to code-base using [tags_like.this] and running a search/replace right before the html is output (not my idea!). Many of the strings live in the database. These strings that live in the database are also modifiable from the front end using forms. Going to one of these forms would show the translated value in the inputs not the tag. Form gets submitted, tag broken.

Comment: The long term solution is obvious... don't be lazy, do it properly by translating when generating the output, not after it is already generated right before sending it to the end user.